# Problem with calling jquery ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax.net, parse-error

i am having a strange problem, while calling ajax jquery in asp.net.. i am getting the parseError, and this is not expected, because everything is in place.

below is my webmethod.

```
public class MyLogic
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    private string _title, _image;

    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }
}
```

below is the method i am calling

```
[WebMethod]
    public static MyLogic[] GetTopArticles()
    {
        List<MyLogic> bList = new List<MyLogic>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MobileKeyboardConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapTopStories = new SqlDataAdapter("m_sp_toparticles", con);
        adapTopStories.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adapTopStories.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PortalId", 2);
        adapTopStories.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topValue", 5);
        DataTable dtTopStories = new DataTable();
        adapTopStories.Fill(dtTopStories);
        foreach (DataRow r in dtTopStories.Rows)
        {
            MyLogic c = new MyLogic();
            c.Id = Convert.ToInt32(r["Id"]);
            c.Title = r["Title"].ToString();
            c.Image = r["image"].ToString();
            bList.Add(c);
        }
        return bList.ToArray();
    }
```

and below is the design.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxLogic.aspx/GetTopArticles",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.d;
                alert(result.length);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please any know what could be issue
i am using core asp.net and master pages in my application.

*******************************JSON RESPONSE********************************

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="AjaxLogic.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZPKFQelTZBrnZbMRGP+4imyXfwO4" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
data: {},
```

by:

```
data: '{}',
```

Comment: i already checked that but that too not working, i replaced with double quotes but no change, isnt it the issue of masterpage.. could it be? is ajax jquery supported in masterpage

Comment: @Abbas, no, unrelated to masterpages. Try looking in FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools at the AJAX request being sent and the exact response from the server. Also you may try completely removing the `data` parameter from your ajax request.

Comment: i checked under firebug, it says 200 OK, but under Net --> Post -- > it says There is no child object.. i dont know why its not getting records. because i called the SP and its giving proper resultset

Comment: @Abbas, when you debug, is the PageMethod on the server being hit?

Comment: @Abbas, and what do you see in the Response tab? What is the exact JSON being sent?

Comment: hi @Darrin i have updated my question with the server response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3707/discussion-between-abbas-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: @Abbas, what happens if you remove the `data` parameter from the request entirely?